why do the env variables not work in my cypress code
i am trying to integrate cypress and 1password together for safer automated testing. i have one test where i login, navigate, logout of the platform then move to archive and play money for nothing. i would like to do the same test using environment variables where i fetch the necessary login data from 1password. however the test runs early into an error and does not fetch my credentials.
running: "source ./fetchCredentials.sh echo $CYPRESS_EMAIL echo $CYPRESS_PASSWORD" i do in fact get the right credentials.
i have also added the block below to the json file.
{
  "scripts": {
    "cy:run": "source ./fetchCredentials.sh && cypress run",
    "cy:open": "source ./fetchCredentials.sh && cypress open"
  }
}

my sh file to fetch the credentials
#!/bin/bash

# Fetch the email and password from 1Password using the 1Password CLI
email=$(op item get "Mogeniusßß" --vault="Employee" --fields username)
password=$(op item get "Mogeniusßß" --vault="Employee" --fields password)

# Check if the credentials were fetched successfully
if [ -z "$email" ] || [ -z "$password" ]; then
  echo "Failed to fetch credentials from 1Password. Please ensure the item exists and the 1Password CLI is logged in."
  exit 1
fi

# Export the fetched credentials as environment variables
export CYPRESS_EMAIL=$email
export CYPRESS_PASSWORD=$password

for reference this is the first test that runs smoothly, which doesnt use env variables
describe('Login to Mogenius, perform actions, and then play a song', () => {

    it('should log in, handle cookie consent, navigate, and log out of Mogenius', () => {
        // Your actual login credentials
        const email = '**********************';
        const password = '********************';

        // Visit the login page
        cy.visit('https://app.dev.mogenius.com/user/login');

        // Handle "Accept & Close" cookie consent button if it appears
        cy.get('button#ppms_cm_agree-to-all').then(($btn) => {
            if ($btn.is(':visible')) {
                cy.wrap($btn).click(); // Click the "Accept & Close" button
            }
        });

        // Enter the email using the placeholder attributex
        cy.get('input[placeholder="Email"]').type(email);

        // Enter the password using the placeholder attribute
        cy.get('input[placeholder="Password"]').type(password);

        // Click the login button
        cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click();

        // Assert that the login was successful by checking the URL or some element that appears after login
        cy.url().should('include', 'https://app.dev.mogenius.com/studio/settings/organizations');

        // Wait for the DemoOrg element to be visible and click it
        cy.get('span.fw-bold.me-auto.text-truncate.flex-shrink-1').contains('DemoOrg').should('be.visible').click();

        // Assert that the URL has changed to the DemoOrg page
        cy.url().should('include', '/studio/organization/35bdd042-fcb7-4afd-af03-9feffe1dbae1');

        // Wait for the JanGKE project element to be visible and click it
        cy.get('span.h6.text-truncate').contains('JanGKE').should('be.visible').click();

        // Wait for the EY element to be visible and click it
        cy.get('div.container').contains('EY').should('be.visible').click();

        // Wait for the Logout element to be visible and click it
        cy.get('a.dropdown-item').contains('Logout').should('be.visible').click();

        // Optionally, assert that the URL has changed to the login page
        cy.url().should('include', 'app.dev.mogenius.com/user/login');
    });

    it('play Money for Nothing', {includeShadowDom: true, scrollBehavior: false}, () => {
        // Set preferable screen resolution
        cy.viewport(1500, 1500);

        // Page base URL
        cy.visit('https://archive.org/details/10.-telegraph-road-live-remix_202303');

        // Handle any cookie consent or similar pop-ups on this page if they exist
        //cy.get('button#ppms_cm_agree-to-all').then(($btn) => {
            //if ($btn.is(':visible')) {
               // cy.wrap($btn).click(); // Click the "Accept & Close" button
           // }
        //});

        // Play "Money For Nothing" - Track #11
        cy.contains('button', 'Money For Nothing').click();
    });
});

i expect, having provided the details above for cypress to run smoothly through my test which is as follows:
describe('Login to Mogenius, perform actions, and then play a song', () => {
    it('should log in, handle cookie consent, navigate, and log out of Mogenius', () => {
        // Use the credentials from the environment variables
        const email = Cypress.env('CYPRESS_EMAIL');
        const password = Cypress.env('CYPRESS_PASSWORD');

        // Ensure the variables are correctly loaded
        //if (!email || !password) {
            //throw new Error('CYPRESS_EMAIL or CYPRESS_PASSWORD is not set');
        //}

        // Visit the login page
        cy.visit('https://app.dev.mogenius.com/user/login');

        // Handle "Accept & Close" cookie consent button if it appears
        cy.get('button#ppms_cm_agree-to-all').then(($btn) => {
            if ($btn.is(':visible')) {
                cy.wrap($btn).click(); // Click the "Accept & Close" button
            }
        });

        // Enter the email using the placeholder attribute
        cy.get('input[placeholder="Email"]').type(email);

        // Enter the password using the placeholder attribute
        cy.get('input[placeholder="Password"]').type(password);

        // Click the login button
        cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click();

        // Assert that the login was successful by checking the URL or some element that appears after login
        cy.url().should('include', 'https://app.dev.mogenius.com/studio/settings/organizations');

        // Wait for the DemoOrg element to be visible and click it
        cy.get('span.fw-bold.me-auto.text-truncate.flex-shrink-1').contains('DemoOrg').should('be.visible').click();

        // Assert that the URL has changed to the DemoOrg page
        cy.url().should('include', '/studio/organization/35bdd042-fcb7-4afd-af03-9feffe1dbae1');

        // Wait for the JanGKE project element to be visible and click it
        cy.get('span.h6.text-truncate').contains('JanGKE').should('be.visible').click();

        // Wait for the EY element to be visible and click it
        cy.get('div.container').contains('EY').should('be.visible').click();

        // Wait for the Logout element to be visible and click it
        cy.get('a.dropdown-item').contains('Logout').should('be.visible').click();

        // Optionally, assert that the URL has changed to the login page
        cy.url().should('include', 'app.dev.mogenius.com/user/login');
    });

    it('play Money for Nothing', { includeShadowDom: true, scrollBehavior: false }, () => {
        // Set preferable screen resolution
        cy.viewport(1500, 1500);

        // Page base URL
        cy.visit('https://archive.org/details/10.-telegraph-road-live-remix_202303');

        // Play "Money For Nothing" - Track #11
        cy.contains('button', 'Money For Nothing').click();
    });
});

unfortunately i get the following error:



6
type

(xhr)POST https://px.ads.linkedin.com/wa/




CypressError
cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefinedLearn more
cypress/e2e/1-getting-started/env2.cy.js:23:46
  21 |
  22 |         // Enter the email using the placeholder attribute
> 23 |         cy.get('input[placeholder="Email"]').type(email);
     |                                              ^
  24 |
  25 |         // Enter the password using the placeholder attribute
  26 |         cy.get('input[placeholder="Password"]').type(password);

it is confusing that running : source ./fetchCredentials.sh
echo $CYPRESS_EMAIL
echo $CYPRESS_PASSWORD does give me the true credentials but somehow they dont get fetched during the test run.
help would be very much appreciated

From Overriding environment variables

Cypress automatically removes the leading CYPRESS_ or cypress_ from any environment variable name specified in this way.

Therefore when setting CYPRESS_EMAIL & CYPRESS_PASSWORD externally, you want this in your test code:
const email = Cypress.env('EMAIL');
const password = Cypress.env('PASSWORD');


also need to run the right commands to engage with 1password but thanks for the help as well
